# MySQL Select INTO csv file separator working incorrectly

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to export some data to csv but facing some issue with the "," delemeter.

I am running the below query:

```
SELECT c.NAME 
  FROM company c
 WHERE COMPANY_ID = 1 
  INTO OUTFILE 'E:\\ab.csv' FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

If my name does not contain any "," then the csv is correctly populated but if my "name" field contains "," then data is split into two rows.

For ex:
c.Name = "Google INC"    ->  Works fine
c.Name = "Google,INC"    ->  it creates csv with two different column "Google" and "INC".

Kindly suggest what should I do.

Comment: see this example https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/02/04/how-to-remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-while-importing-a-data-file/

Comment: is this sql-server or mysql?

Comment: @GeomanYabesin SQL Server but I think it's possible to work in MySQL too.

Comment: i think you got it wrong @Krismorte. OP's code is MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link at the comment you can try something like this

```
SELECT c.NAME 
  FROM company c
 WHERE COMPANY_ID = 1 
  INTO OUTFILE 'E:\\ab.csv' FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' TERMINATED BY '",' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Marking `",` instead `,`